# How to compute a median in PrestoSQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, presto, median

It seems like there is no native function for that purpose in Presto SQL. Do you know any way to efficiently aggregate a group and return its median?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`approx_percentile()`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#approx_percentile) should be a reasonable approach. Assuming a table like `mytable(id, val)`, that you want to aggregate by `id`:

```
select id, approx_percentile(val, 0.5) median_val
from mytable
group by id
```

Comment: Note that this is an approximate solution. Upcoming Presto release will provide more accuracy in general case, follow https://github.com/prestosql/presto/pull/5158 for details.

Answer (score 1):

Well in my case, I am using Presto and the most-voted solution didn't work, so I had to do it in 2 CTEs:

1. I used the row_number() to number all the rows over my sequence of values in the order desired
2. I discovered the row in the middle by dividing the max(row_number) by 2 (in my case there was no need to treat odd or even numbers)
3. Inner join to my original data, where I just select the records with the same row_number as the CTE 2

(it might not be the best logic, but I did it in a rush and worked fine)